# How to build Meego Mobile application using HTML5 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-application, meego

Can i build Mobile application for Meego using HTML5 and Javascript?

Comment: Please be more constructive with your question - what have you tried?

Comment: I have installed Meego sdk 1.2 and just want to make Meego app using Qt Creator.So can i use HTML5 and js to make the app along with C++ .

Comment: The question should probably be "can I" instead of "how to"

Answer (score 2):

How to build a skyscraper using bricks and mortar?

How to eat a cake using knife and fork?

How to accelerate through time and space using a ladder and a light switch?

....

In answer to your question: To build a mobile app for Meego using HTML5 and Javascript you would need to learn HTML5 and Javascript, get the Meego API and make the app...